# IE 11 Operating System is not Supported

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, operating-systems

Am trying to install IE 11 in windows 7 professional 32 bit OS but it showing error. please find the attachment you get know..please help me out this issue...

Error Like, "operating system is not supported. you need windows 7 SP1 or Windows 2008R2 SP1 to install Internet Explorer 11".

Please give me the solutions this issue.
Thanks and Regards,
Chella

Comment: It sounds like you are running an unsupported version of Windows.  Considering upgrading to Windows 7 SP1, Windows 8.1 Update 1, or Windows 10 if you want to run IE11

Answer (score 2):

Go to Computer > Properties and see if you have Service Pack 1 Installed on your Windows 7.  If not, you have to install it using Windows Update or the offline installation [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5842).

[image]

Comment: … then get the other 150 updates you've missed, too.